# A small app-crawler created using python

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written some code using python having tried to comply with OOP design for the purpose of collecting name of the app, price and developer name from i-tune site by going deeper until there is a limit [which can be toggled within my script] to stop as it has millions of links to go. It is working impeccably at this moment. I tried my best to make this scraper pythonic. However, suggestions to bring about any change to make this crawler more robust will be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class app_scraper:

    start_url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8"

    def __init__(self):

        self.links = [self.start_url]
        self.vault = []

    def crawler(self):

        for url in self.links:
            self.get_app(url)

    def get_app(self, url):

        print("Scraping now "+ url)
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        name = tree.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
        developer = tree.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/h2/text()')[0]
        price = tree.xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]/text()')[0]

        item = processor(name, developer, price)
        self.vault.append(item)

        p_links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="lockup-info"]//li/a[@class="name"]/@href')
        for p_link in p_links:
            if not len(self.links)>=5:  # It'll stop crawling until it meets the limit whatever it is
                self.links += [p_link]


class processor:

    def __init__(self, name, developer, price):

        self.name = name
        self.developer = developer
        self.price = price


    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name+" "+self.price+" "+self.developer)

crawl = app_scraper()
crawl.crawler()

for info in crawl.vault:
    print(info)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job improving the modularity of your code under reviews.

We can improve the following:

- follow Python's naming convention and use camel-case style names for your classes
- let's as usual reuse a `Session` instance
- let's also use `findtext()` to get element texts
- I would either use [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for your "processor"s or use `__slots__`

Improved code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests


class AppScraper:
    start_url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8"

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

        self.links = [self.start_url]
        self.vault = []

    def crawler(self):

        for url in self.links:
            self.get_app(url)

    def get_app(self, url):
        print("Scraping now "+ url)

        page = self.session.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        name = tree.findtext('.//h1[@itemprop="name"]')
        developer = tree.findtext('.//div[@class="left"]/h2')
        price = tree.findtext('.//div[@itemprop="price"]')

        item = Processor(name, developer, price)
        self.vault.append(item)

        p_links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="lockup-info"]//li/a[@class="name"]/@href')
        for p_link in p_links:
            if len(self.links) < 5:  # It'll stop crawling until it meets the limit whatever it is
                self.links += [p_link]


class Processor:
    __slots__ = ['name', 'developer', 'price']

    def __init__(self, name, developer, price):
        self.name = name
        self.developer = developer
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.price + " " + self.developer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawl = AppScraper()
    crawl.crawler()

    for info in crawl.vault:
        print(info)
```

Comment: A little question on this _slots_ stuff. What is it doing here? As a newbie I'm not familiar with this. I hope you will let me know. Thanks sir.

Comment: @SMth80 ah, yes, good findings - on a new machine, have to adjust to the new environment :) `__slots__` should provide a boost in performance if you are going to instantiate lots of instances. Thanks!